# image rollover object - javascript

Tags: javascript, rollover

The following is a simple bit of code that can be used to create image rollovers (taken from a tutorial that I'm going through).  The author says: under the attach event handlers part, the constructor creates the two event handlers here.  It's within these event handlers that the variable named "that" has to be used to refer to the Rollover object.  That's because the "this" keyword within the event handlers refers to the image object, not the Rollover object.

My question is: I understand that `this.image` refers to the image object but wouldn't you want to just set `this.image.src` equal to `this.newImageURL`?  I guess I just don't understand why `that` is necessary.  And how is it that changing the src property of `that.image` ends up changing the src property of `this.image?'

```
var $ = function (id) { return document.getElementById(id); }

var Rollover = function ( imageId, newImageURL ) {
    var that = this;
    this.newImageURL = newImageURL;
    this.image = $(imageId);

    // Validate node
    if ( ! this.image ) {
        throw new Error("Rollover: Image ID not found.");
    }
    if ( this.image.nodeType !== 1 || this.image.nodeName !== "IMG" ) {
        throw new Error("Rollover: Image ID is not an img tag.");
    }

    var newObj = that;
    // Copy original image url
    this.oldImageURL = this.image.src;

    // Attach event handlers
    this.image.onmouseover = function () {
        that.image.src = that.newImageURL;
    }
    this.image.onmouseout = function () {
        that.image.src = that.oldImageURL;
    }
}
```

Comment: `that` is used because in `this.image.onmouseover/out`, `this` refers to the image element, not the object constructed by `Rollover`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript the **this** variable changes with scope. The first line of `var that = this;` **this** refers to the Rollover object. Setting that = this basically just creates a pointer to Rollover.

In any subsequent event call like

```
this.image.onmouseover = function () {
    that.image.src = that.newImageURL;
}
```

In the function callback **this** now refers to the event scope - **this** now points to the object that was rolled over. Thats why this.image wouldn't point to anything because the DOM element being moused over does not have an image property. Because you already set another variable (that) to the Rollover instance (original **this**), you can now use it in any of the other scopes.

Answer (score 0):

This refers to the instance of the object instanceated at that time the constructor is created.
That is why it's important - or the clr would not know what object to call? with.
(this is my first answer please be kind ;))

Answer (score 0):

You no longer should use javascript for rollovers.

Try CSS:hover! http://tinkerbin.com/ze1Y32ZP